# Can I adapt from XMLEventWriter to XMLStreamWriter?

Tags: xml-parsing, stax, jaxp

In order to support a StAXResult as input, I'd like to be able to adapt from XMLEventWriter to XMLStreamWriter.  Its possible to go in the other direction via XMLOutputFactory2.createXMLEventWriter(XMLStreamWriter).

There's a similar asymmetry for readers as XMLInputFactory only has a method to adapt from XMLStreamReader to XMLEventReader.

Is there a way to do this?

NB: My code currently uses an XMLStreamWriter internally so it would be trivial to support an XMLStreamWriter.  To support XMLEventWriter I either need to adapt the writer or change all the internal code to use XMLEventWriter (given that I *can* adapt from XMLStreamWriter to XMLEventWriter).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, you can use XMLEventStreamWriter from stax-utils.